# Android 2.3 webview file upload issue

Tags: android, file-upload, webview

I'm using webview to run my web application, 
In my app I'm allowing the user to upload images to my server, everything is working fine on android > 3, on Android 2.3.3 browser it also working as expected but on the webview the file is not populated in the  and my server is getting an empty object.
It is happening only when I'm taking the picture from the camera (i.e. regular gallery is working fine).
I noticed the the Uri are different one with file:/// and one with content:///

Attached is my code:
HTML (my simple test page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<form id="fuForm" name="fuForm" action="/questions/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

MainActivity code:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeViewClient());  
    webView.loadUrl(url);


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        private class MyWebChromeViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
            //@Override
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType )  {      
                 File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
                // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
                if (! imageStorageDir.exists()){
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();                  
                }
                File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");  
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
                for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                    final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                    intent.setPackage(packageName);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    cameraIntents.add(intent);
                }


                uploadMessage = uploadMsg; 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
                intent.setType("image/*"); 
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,  FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE); 
            }

   // For Android < 3.0
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

    }

   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == uploadMessage)
                return;
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (intent == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action
                            .equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
            Uri result;
            if (isCamera) {
                result = imageUri;
            } else {
                result = intent == null ? null : intent.getData();
            }
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        } else {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        uploadMessage = null;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Joe.

Comment: As I didn't find any other solution in the net, I'm just converting my pictures to scheme content (from file) using ContentResolver, this is solving my problems.

However I'm still looking for an answer why it is working on android > 3 and not in 2.3 and if the is a simpler way???.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying something similiar but I miss a lot of imports, could you added?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, but I have found a solution by myself after a long time research.

On the Android 2.3.3, the webview doesn’t support the Uri with file protocol (file:///). We should convert the image’s Uri to a content protocol Uri (content:///) before calling uploadMessage.onReceiveValue.The varaiable imageFilePath in below code is the absolute path of the image file captured by camera.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == uploadMessage)
            return;
        final boolean isCamera;
        if (intent == null) {
            isCamera = true;
        } else {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action == null) {
                isCamera = false;
            } else {
                isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
        Uri result;
        if (isCamera) {
            **String mediaUri =MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),imageFilePath,"","");
            result = Uri.parse(mediaUri);**
        } else {
            result = intent == null ? null : intent.getData();
        }
        uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
    } else {
        uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
    }
    uploadMessage = null;
}
```